# Why is {System.Web.Mvc.SelectList} DropDownList SelectedValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, selectedvalue, html-select

I have created a DropDownList, as described in my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301235/selecting-a-value-from-a-dropdownlist-to-be-able-to-fill-in-fields)

I have been trying to figure out how to get the selected value of the list. I used the answer that was provided but the only thing it returned was `{System.Web.Mvc.SelectList}`
I debugged it and sure enough the string that was in the "Value" column was `{System.Web.Mvc.SelectList}`

What am I doing wrong here? I have been miserably failing at MVC and am new at it.

Thank you for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793585/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc or accept (int OrganizationID) in your ActionResult.

Comment: This does not help because the value that resides in the dropdownlist is {System.Web.Mvc.SelectList}. It does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Action in your controller should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int DropOrgId)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  return null;
}
```

The important thing to note is that "**DropOrgId**" is the same as the string name you passed into @Html.DropDownList("**DropOrgID**") in your view.  This name will store the value of the input from the HTML input control, in this case the

The source will be:

```
<select id="DropOrgID" name="DropOrgID">...</select>
```

The id of the input control is how the MVC framework will match up the value of that control to the parameter of the action you are looking for.

Here is a sample app that shows it:

Class

```
  public class Organization
  {
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Controller

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var orgs = new List<Organization>();
      foreach (var count in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
      {
        var newOrg = new Organization();

        newOrg.OrganizationID = count;
        newOrg.Name = "Organization " + count.ToString();

        orgs.Add(newOrg);
      }

      ViewBag.DropOrgID = new SelectList(orgs, "OrganizationID", "Name", 3);

      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int DropOrgID)
    {
      //You can check that this DropOrgID contains the newly selected value.
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Index View

```
<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownList("DropOrgID")
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And thank you again for explaining it so clearly!